# why routing is not working when tap on the notification in flutter? ( the project is based on GetX and flutter local push notification package )

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-notification

Good day.
I know that we use the onSelectNotification property to get the callback when the user tap on the notification in using the flutter local push notification package.

```
  Future<void> _initialize() async {
    await _configureLocalTimeZone();
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        IOSInitializationSettings(
            onDidReceiveLocalNotification: _onDidReceiveLocalNotification);

    InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: _onSelectNotification);        // This is for the callback
  }
```

This is the _onSelectsNotification function.

```
  Future _onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      print('notification payload: $payload');
    }
    BuildContext context;
    await Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return NotificationsView();
    }));                           // ***** This is not working. with no error.
  }
```

I am not sure what to use for the context. I think the next route to the NotificationView() is not working because of the context value.
Could you please help me with this issue?
I am now using the GetX for the state management.

Thanks.

Comment: @pskink thanks. I have tried. but not working. :( 
This is because of the context that I used?

Comment: Is the payload printed?

Comment: @Spike, Thanks for the reaching out. yes, payload is printed well. I have tested just now.

Comment: ahh, of course its related to context, you cannot use `null` context: `BuildContext context;`

Comment: @pskink, thanks... really, from your approach, I have solved this problem right now.

Comment: The `context` you are using in `Navigator.of` is null, pass a correct context instead (like the context in the State class).

Comment: I have solved this issue with Get.to()

Comment: By the way. I know that the context I use is now null.
then, How to get the context from the State Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with Get.toNamed()
My fault was in not returning in the _onSelectNotification function.

```
  Future _onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      print('notification payload: $payload');
    }
    return Get.toNamed(Routes.NOTIFICATIONS);
  }
```

This is working well.

But I still don't know how to get the context from another state class.
In the previous post, I passed the null for the context.
I know that this was wrong. How to get?

Answer (score 0):

The code is not working because, at the time you call your Navigator, the widget is not finished building. A simple fix is to wrap the `Navigator.of(context)` with Future, like this:

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_){
Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return NotificationsView();
    }
  ));
});
```